# Why does $29^2 : 31^2 : 41^2$ have a close integer approximation with small numbers?

Tags: diophantine-approximation

"Everybody knows" that such coincidences as

$$2\times2\times\overbrace{41\times41} = 6724 \approx 6728 = 2\times2\times2\times\overbrace{29\times29}$$

(And why did I bother with the first two factors of $2$ on each side?  Be patient.)

are "explained" by the fact that $\dfrac{41}{29}$ is a convergent in the simple continued fraction expansion of $\sqrt 2$. and maybe

$$2\times2\times2\times\overbrace{29\times29} = 6728 \approx 6727 = 7\times\overbrace{31\times31}$$

has a similar "explanation", as presumably would the fact that

$$2\times2\times\overbrace{41\times41} = 6724 \approx 6727 = 7\times\overbrace{31\times31}.$$

Is there some such "explanation" of the simultaneous proximity of all three of these numbers to each other?

Comment: interesting, I will see if I can come up with such a thing. Your three quadratic forms are $\pm$ the principal forms of three discriminants, rather equivalent to.

Comment: I don't know whether this is relevant, but $41^2-31^2=720=6!$ and
$31^2-29^2=120=5!$

Comment: I think Tito is right, in his answer, but a similar set of correspondences can be obtained from the Pell-like equations $x^2 = \frac{8}{7}y^2+1$ (which yields the solutions $(15, 14), (449, 420), \ldots$) and $x^2 = \frac{7}{4}y^2+1$ (which yields the solutions $(8, 6), (127, 96), \ldots$).

Comment: @BrianTung: I've edited my answer for clarity. Can you give examples of proximate triples $x_1,x_2,x_3$ similar to $29,\,31,\,41$  using your pair of Pell-like eqns?

Comment: Would you consider $24\approx25\approx27$ similar?
$$24=6\times\overbrace{2\times2}$$
$$25=1\times\overbrace{5\times5}$$
$$27=3\times\overbrace{3\times3}$$

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII: I'm not sure that you can come up with triples like that.  I haven't given it much thought, though.

Comment: @JaumeOliverLafont: If, as in my answer, we assume that Hardy required ***both*** $x_1 \approx x_2 \approx x_3$ and $ax_1^2 \approx bx_2^2 \approx cx_3^2$, then $2,3,5$ would be such a triple. But it's more non-trivial to find those with two, three, or four digits.

Answer (score 7):

I think it's just the law of small numbers. I'm assuming you want distinct triples $x_1,x_2,x_3$ such that $x_1\approx x_2\approx x_3$ as well as $ax_1^2\approx bx_2^2\approx cx_3^2$ with distinct $a,b,c$. If so, yours was the first of several examples and *Mathematica* quickly finds,

$$\begin{aligned}
6724&= 4\times41^2\\
6727&= 7\times31^2\\
6728&= 8\times29^2\\
\end{aligned}\tag1$$

$$\begin{aligned}
7935 &= 15\times23^2\\
7938 &= 18\times21^2\\
7942 &= 22\times19^2\\
\end{aligned}\tag2$$

$$\begin{aligned}
18490&= 10\times43^2\\
18491&= 11\times41^2\\
18496&= 16\times34^2\\
\end{aligned}\tag3$$

$$\begin{aligned}
55223&= 23\times49^2\\
55225&= 25\times47^2\\
55233&= 17\times57^2\\
\end{aligned}\tag4$$

And that's just the results by using certain assumptions, such as two of the numbers $x_i$ being squared are "twin numbers", i.e $47,49$, which differ by $2$. More generous assumptions and relaxing $x_1-x_2 = 2$ would probably net more results.

Answer (score 6):

$$2\times2\times\overbrace{41\times41} = \overbrace{82\times82} \approx 7\times\overbrace{31\times31}.$$

This is due the fact that $$\cfrac{82}{31}=2+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{4+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{1}}}}}}$$

is a convergent of the simple continued fraction of $\sqrt{7}$.

Those two can be combined to get the result.

Comment: But again, that's just one of the three unordered pairs of proximate numbers.  Is there a similar reason why all three are simultaneously close together?  That was the question. $\qquad$

Comment: I changed $$\frac{82}{31}=2+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{4+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1}}}}}}$$ to $$\cfrac{82}{31}=2+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{4 + \cfrac{1}{1 + \cfrac{1}{1}}}}}}.$$  That is why \cfrac exists. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2):

> Because
>   $$\sqrt{2}=\sqrt{\frac{8}{7}}\sqrt{\frac{7}{4}}\approx\frac{31}{29}\times\frac{41}{31}=\frac{41}{29}$$

We may group the three numbers into one single expression 
$$4+6724\times6728=(6727-1)^2$$
that can be written as 
$$\left(\frac{6727-1}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{6724}{2}\times\frac{6728}{2}\right)=1 $$
or
$$\left(\frac{7\times31^2-1}{2}\right)^2-2\left(2\times 29 \times 41\right)^2=1 $$

This is Pell's equation
$$X^2-dY^2=1$$

with $X=\frac{7\times31^2-1}{2}$, $Y={2\times29\times41}$ and $d=2$,

so the corresponding approximation to $\sqrt{2}$ is given by
$$\sqrt{2}\approx\frac{7\times31^2-1}{4\times29\times41}=\frac{(31\sqrt{7}+1)(31\sqrt{7}-1)}{4\times29\times41}=\frac{3363}{2378}$$
which is the [tenth convergent of the continued fraction expansion](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%5BFromContinuedFraction%5BContinuedFraction%5B(Sqrt%5B2%5D),+n%5D%5D,+%7Bn,+15%7D%5D).

Factoring the numerator shows that the square in 6727 is related to $\sqrt{7}$, as in the [answer by wythagoras](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1711930/134791).

A simpler example is given by

$$\begin{align}98&=2\times7^2\\
99&=11\times3^2\\
100&=1\times10^2
\end{align}$$
with 
$$99^2-98\times100=1$$

and $$\sqrt{2}\approx\frac{11\times3^2}{7\times10}=\frac{99}{70}$$

Approximating $\sqrt{2}$ with the sixth convergent explains the squares of $7$ and $10$, but we also need 
$$\sqrt{\frac{11}{1}}\approx\frac{10}{3}$$
and / or
$$\sqrt{\frac{11}{2}}\approx\frac{7}{3}$$
to justify the square of $3$.

In this example, the approximation for $\sqrt{2}$ can be obtained by direct multiplication of the approximations for $\sqrt{\frac{2}{11}}$ and $\sqrt{\frac{1}{11}}$, but this is not the case in the example from the question.

$$\sqrt{2}=11\sqrt{\frac{2}{11}}\sqrt{\frac{1}{11}}\approx11\times\frac{3}{7}\times\frac{3}{10}=\frac{99}{70}$$

However, dividing the approximations implied by the equations involving number $7$, the convergent $\sqrt{2} \approx \frac{41}{29}$ is obtained.

$$\sqrt{2}=\sqrt{\frac{8}{7}}\sqrt{\frac{7}{4}}\approx\frac{31}{29}\times\frac{41}{31}=\frac{41}{29}$$